# Как узнать ширину LinearLayout в recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, admob

Возможно не совсем грамотно выразился. Суть такова. У меня есть Recyclerview. Я для него написал свой адаптер. Там есть 3 вида ячеек. В зависимости от вида ячейки подключается свой шаблон (layout). Один из видов ячеек рекламный. Для него подключается такой layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

В адаптере этот шаблон подключается так:

```java
    public PostFeedAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        this.mContext = parent.getContext();
        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case HEADER:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_header_layout, parent, false);
                return new RecyclerViewHolder(view, viewType, headerType, header.parsed() && header.isFriendignoreBtnsEnabled());
            case POST:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_post_layout, parent, false);
                return new RecyclerViewHolder(view, viewType, headerType, header.parsed() && header.isFriendignoreBtnsEnabled());
            case ADVERT:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adspost_layout, parent, false);
                return new RecyclerViewHolder(view, viewType, headerType, header.parsed() && header.isFriendignoreBtnsEnabled());
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

А именно это adspost_layout. Чтобы сделать запрос рекламы, мне надо задать размеры рекламного блока. В примерах кода гугла я нашёл вот такой метод:

```java
mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
        final int adWidth = lv.getWidth();
    }
});
```

Но у меня этот способ не срабатывает. У меня lv получается null, поэтому я не могу достать её размер. Честно говоря я впервые встречаю метод .post(new Runnable(), поэтому не совсем понимаю как он работает и что надо сделать, чтобы он правильно работал.

Как же мне получить правильную ширину LinearLayout?

Comment: Если никаких больше нигде отступов нет, то почему бы просто ширину экрана не отдавать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я тоже так думал, но в примере гугла, я подставлял свой шаблон (где чисто LinearLayout) и как оказывалось его ширина 608, когда ширина экрана 640.

Comment: Значит у вас там отступов на 32 пикселя. Ищите их в разметке

Comment: если вы хотите использовать нативную рекламу, то скорее всего в ней уже есть специальный wrapper для вашего адаптера, к примеру в MoPub есть MoPubRecyclerAdapter

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вообще насчёт подставления ширины экрана вы всё-таки правы) Проверил, подставил ширину экрана и всё нормально вписалось. Спасибо за совет.